# Will a Pentax K-1 charge a battery in the camera?

Tags: battery, pentax

If I plug in the Pentax K-1 to a wall socket using the adapter, will it charge the battery if I leave the "on/off" switch "off"? And will it still charge the battery if I leave it "on", just at a slower rate??

Comment: Do we really need a separate version of this question every time a new camera model is introduced?

Comment: @MichaelClark, except in this case, the K-1 has an actual adapter port as well as the USB one. "Using the adapter" suggested the latter might be what's discussed here.

Comment: @inkista If the question were about *powering the camera* I might agree. But the question is about *charging the battery*.

Comment: @MichaelClark except that the OP is clearly confused as to whether the adapter is charging the battery or not. And if he isn't asking about the USB port at all, then how does it get duplicated by a question specifically about USB port power?

Comment: The root question is, *Can I charge my battery inside my DSLR?* The answer continues to be *No* for all known models.

Comment: @MichaelClark If your duplicate was reworded to be "in-camera" instead of "via USB", maybe. But it isn't.

Comment: We've got plenty of dupes where the original question is about a Canon lens or camera and the duplicate question is about the same thing on a Nikon or Pentax or Sony. As long as the root question is the same and the brand doesn't matter we generally consider them duplicates.

Answer (score 5):

If, by "using the adapter", you mean plugging in a USB cable to the camera's USB port, no. The USB cable is for file transfer only, and does not charge anything.

If, by "using the adapter", you mean plugging in an AC power adapter into the DC input port, then again, no. The adapter itself takes the place of the battery and bypasses it; it does not charge the battery.

Answer (score 1):

No. Most DSLRs - actually, I know none that does - do not have an integrated charging circuit.